# return the number of nodes in a python file by a path of length

Tags: python, graph, edges

I got a hard problem in python for my last question of project.

Imagine you get a file like it :

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

- if node 1 is linked to node 2 by an edge then 2 is accessible by a path of length 1 from 1: 1-2
- if 1 is linked to 2 itself to 3 and itself to 4 then 4 is accessible by a path of length 4 from 1: 1-2-3-4
- I want to return the number of nodes accessible from a given node by a path of length 3 by default

thanks for advice  and help !!!!

EDIT :

```
def bfs(graph, start_node, distance):
    if distance == 0:
        return [start_node]
    visited = []
    queue = []
    nodes_at_dist = []

    level = 0
    visited.append(start_node)
    queue.append((start_node, level))
```

Comment: Create a set of nodes which can be accessed from given node directly. This set is the nodes accessible by path length 1. Iterate through set to create new set of nodes directly accessible from the nodes of first set. This set has then all nodes accessible with path length 2. Repeat with newly created set to find nodes for length 3 and so on.

Comment: yes I gave a simple example, but in reality, I have like 5000 number with  lot of node ... But I have no idea how I can realize it in python

Comment: Try to follow the described steps and ask here with your code if you have a specific issue.

Comment: I edit my answer to show you

Comment: did you delete your answer ?

Comment: I saw you deleted your last post where I posted an answer. Did you try with that? You have put an incomplete code here from that post I guess.

Comment: yes exactely, I tried with your code, it worked but I unterstand nothing tbh about your code,    It is my bonus question of project, and I try to unterstand what you did, but even this answer I don't unterstand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we rebuild the data structure to simplify the lookup, i.e., which nodes are reachable. I assume that our graph is undirected.

```
graph = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 4), (2, 6), (6, 7)]

# we restructure our input to simplify the lookup
graph_dict = {}
for n1, n2 in graph:
    if n1 not in graph_dict:
        graph_dict[n1] = set()
    if n2 not in graph_dict:
          graph_dict[n2] = set()
    graph_dict[n1].add(n2)
    graph_dict[n2].add(n1)
```

As a result, we have a `dict` where the keys are all existing nodes and the corresponding value is a set of all nodes which are directly connected:

```
{1: {2, 4}, 2: {1, 3, 6}, 3: {2, 4}, 4: {1, 3}, 6: {2, 7}, 7: {6}}
```

The next part is essentially our method which finds the reachable nodes in respect of a fixed distance:

```
def bfs(graph_dict, start_node, distance):
    # We reached the end and return the current node
    if distance == 0:
        return {start_node}
        
    # We look-up all nodes which are reachable with one step
    reachable = graph_dict[start_node]
        
    # Now we iterate through this set and call our method again (recursively)
    result=set()
    for node in reachable:
        tmp=bfs(graph_dict, node, distance-1)
        result=result.union(tmp)
    return result
```

**Example Output 1: distance=2, start_node=1**

```
{1, 3, 6}
```

Please note that "1" is in our result set because we can walk 1-2-1 (which are two steps).

**Example Output 2: distance=3, start_node=1**

```
{2, 4, 7}
```

Please note that "2" is in our result set because we can walk 1-2-1-2 (which are three steps).

Comment: I just edited it. Please try it again. There was an error in line `result=result.union(a)`. There was a `b` instead of `result`. Please let me know when you get an error which is unrelated.

Comment: yes, i corrected this error but it is about a that i got the error

Comment: I corrected my code above -sorry for that! Please replace `result=result.union(a)` with `result=result.union(tmp)` and replace `result=bfs(graph_dict, node, distance-1)` with `tmp=bfs(graph_dict, node, distance-1)`

Comment: ok thanks you !! Now can I ask you some questions to unterstand ?

Comment: Sure -then I will update my answer accordingly. If the answer was correct please accept it. Please look here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223957/discussion-between-sztyler-and-jean-pierre).